# HTML5 local storage issue

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage, jquery-mobile

I'm having this issue with local storage in HTML5. The code is as follows: `key1` is a question, and `value1` and `value2` are values from radio buttons that I want checked.

```
function setAnswers() {

    $(function () {
        if ($('#id1').is(':checked')) {
            alert(localStorage['key1'] = "value1");
        }

        if ($('#id2').is(':checked')) {
            alert(localStorage['key1'] = "value2");
        }
    });
}
```

and the HTML:

```
   <div id="next1">
       <a class="next" type="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" value="Next"
        data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="page2.html" data-rel="external" onClick="alert(setAnswers())">Next</a>
       </div>
```

So far it works fine with the first `alert()` and even shows the key I stored in `localstorage`, but then I get a second `alert` that says `undefined`, and goes to the next page. when I go back to the first page, it removes the key that I already stored.

EDIT: I posted the wrong code for the `onClick` attribute this is the right one :

```
onClick="alert(setAnswers())"
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Since you are doing `alert(setAnswers())` and `setAnswers` doesn't return anything, you are always going to get an alert with `undefined`. If you only got 2 alerts, then one of your `is` calls is returning false.

Comment: okay, the issue is that I have 2 levels of alerts.. the first one tells me i clicked on this radio button ..and stores it in the localStorage of HTML5 fine ..whichever i choose..it's fine .. however the second level of alert "which is alerting the function setAnswers()" gives me undefined..and moves as per the href to the next page ..but removes the radio button value i stored earlier from the localStorage when i return to the first page .. I'm not sure how can I explain further..

Comment: What's with the extra closing `div` in your HTML?

Comment: oh ..it's for a another opening     div tag that I have for next button ..must've copied it by mistake ..will edit it ..

Comment: @loganfsmyth is correct. Since your setAnswers function doesn't return anything, the second alert will always be undefined. To return the function as you have written, just pass the onclick alert the function name, not its execution: alert(setAnswers). This won't execute the function, though.